# What's the cleanest way to differientiate identical serialized objects?

Tags: java, serialization, exception, jackson, jax-rs

I've got two root exception types my service is throwing

```
class ServiceException extends RuntimeException {
    private Status status;
    private String someString;

    // Boilerplate omitted
} 

class RetryableServiceException extends ServiceException {
    // This class has no new fields
}
```

Because there's a common retry framework our clients will use which determines whether to retry or not based on the exception class.

But the problem, obviously, is that when the client gets the response and calls `Response.readEntity(Class <T> entityType)` they will just get an instance of whatever class they're trying to read, since they have the same fields.

Clearly I need to add some other field which distinguishes these two objects, but how can I add that to the builders and constructors in a way that:

- Doesn't require a ton of client logic,
- doesn't needlessly complicate the exception objects, and
- can be understood by Jackson?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main issue, You don't want to couple the clients and the server so tightly by having the clients use the same exact Exception classes used on the server, create a generic error bean and map exceptions to that bean then serialise/de-serialise it. You can do that in a transparent way using `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper`, this error bean can have `canRetry` or `shouldRetry` fields. An example implementation

```
public class RetryableServiceExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RetryableServiceException> {
@Context
Request request;

public Response toResponse(RetryableServiceException exception) {
    ApiError error = ApiError.builder().canRetry(true).message(exception.getMessage()).build();
    return  Response.status(status).cacheControl(cacheControl).tag(eTag).entity(error).type(APPLICATION_XML);;
    }
}
```